# Can't connect Ubuntu 11.10 with broadband connection

Tags: 11.10

I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 .Before that I used Ubuntu 10.10 .  In 10.10
I used my broadband by configuring as a DSL connection.But in 11.10 I can't do that.
It can't connect . Every time it says that I'm not connected.What might be the problem?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using wired without a router, here are a couple of tests to run:
Click on the icon in the applet for the network manager and see if networking is enabled. You should see some connection label something like eth0.

Another thing to check is your ip address. You can open up a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) and type ifconfig and report back what it says about your eth0 connection.

Finally you should type lspci in the terminal.

You should see a few Network Adaptors listed. Then post your wireless card's info, here for more specific help (or search for your card's name and the word drivers and Ubuntu or Linux)

For example my card is 
Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)

and so I would search for "Realtek RTL8111 drivers Ubuntu" to get info on how to get my card to work.

Comment: Thanks Bro , I'm using wired connection.And it is my desktop not laptop.I don't use any router.

Comment: I edited my answer with some new requests info.

Comment: When I typed ifconfig I found-